# Android app for strace

Tags: android, debugging, strace

I am using an Android tablet and am looking to debug an app which is causing random reboots.

Is there an app I can install to perform the equivalent of a background `strace` or equivalent  ? How is this normally handled.

I am looking to see if there is an app which is constantly running, logging system events.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can find is [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) which just gives you the LogCat output, which would contain System logs, etc.